# way to remove last table from complete html page jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This one makes me nuts:

I am getting a complete page in success callback of jquery ajax call.

I get page as:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<body>
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table></table>
<table></table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the last table tag completely in my code which is rendered. I tried using parent() but to no luck

Here is my ajax call:

```
$ajax({method: get,url:'mypage.cfm',success: function(data) { $(".mycontainer").html(data)});
```

Comment: What exactly would ```parent()``` do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
$ajax({method: get,url:'mypage.cfm',success: function(data) {
   $(".mycontainer").html(data);
   $(".mycontainer").find("table:last").remove();
 });
```

Comment: `$(".mycontainer").html(data).find("table:last").remove();`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out. I had not tried but it should work.

```
$ajax({method: get,url:'mypage.cfm',success: function(data) {
$(".mycontainer").html(data).find("table:last-child").remove();
});
```

Comment: How is this different from @lpg answer or Roko's comment above?

Comment: `last-child` is used here